# Point of proving operators are bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, soft-question, operator-theory

I've been learning a bit of analysis and a lot of what I've been reading about deals with proving certain operators are $L^p$ bounded, but I haven't seen applications yet to proving that these operators are bounded. So my question is: why do analysts care so much about proving certain operators are bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice example: you may have seen the result that if the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ converges uniformly to $f$, then the functions
$$
g_n(t) = \int_0^t f_n(t)\,dt
$$
will converge uniformly to their limit $g(t) = \int_0^t f(t)\,dt$.  This is a very handy result for computing certain integrals.

Another way to state this result is to state that the linear operator $S:L^{\infty}[0,1] \to L^\infty[0,1]$ given by
$$
[S(f)](t) = \int_0^t f(t)\,dt
$$
is *bounded*, and therefore continuous.

In contrast, we cannot conclude that the same will hold for $f_n'$, even if the $f_n$ are each differentiable.  The "differentiation operator" fails to be bounded, which can make life difficult.

Answer (score 1):

One can prove bounded linear operator is equivalent to continuous linear operator. In short, analysts always want their linear "functions" to be continuous.

Comment: thanks for your response. can you explain why they want their functions to be continuous? in order to prevent an infinite descent of me asking why, I will be more specific: what sorts of problems can be solved by proving certain operators are continuous/bounded

Comment: To be honest, your question is very broad. Let me just say this, if you have a continuous linear operator $T: X\rightarrow Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are some normed linear spaces, then we have estimates of the form $||T(x)|| \leq C||x||$. Since analysts are always trying to estimate/control complicated objects by simpler ones, then we see that the expression basically allow analysts to look at the simpler object $||x||$ instead of the more complicated object $||T(x)||$.